# TextEdit does not show recent documents in Yosemite

Tags: textedit

I am new to Mac OS X Yosemite. How do I make TextEdit show recent documents? When I go to File and select Recent Documents, it does not show the last few documents like it used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the Recent items setting in System Preferences > General set to None:

[image]

Comment: 1 up for a simple answer

Comment: I still have this problem with Adobe Reader application and several others. There are only a few applications that indeed show recents, like Xcode. Should this be a separate question?